# Don't trim when downloading file in SAP

Tags: string, concatenation, abap, space

SAP has trim for downloaded files but I need to add spaces at the end of the string and download the file with these spaces.

I tried to add dash character at the end of the string and then translate the dash characters with space.

My code block is;

```
gt_data-line = 'XXX'.
lv_basamak = STRLEN( gt_data-line ).  "result : 3

CONCATENATE gt_data-line '------' INTO gt_data-line RESPECTING BLANKS. 
TRANSLATE gt_data-line USING '- '.

lv_basamak = STRLEN( gt_data-line ).  "result : 9
```

But when I download the file there is not any space at the end of the string.

What can I do for adding spaces?

Comment: Could you please provide a COMPLETE code sample? We can't even see your variable declarations or your function or method call you use for downloading.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the class `CL_GUI_FRONTEND_SERVICES` with method `GUI_DOWNLOAD`. Convert your content to a binary string ( convert to xstring or table of xstring ) and download as binary ( filetype = 'BIN' ).

Comment: An if (s)he's not using a string at all but a character variable that has the documented and intended behaviour of removing trailing spaces? That's why I wanted to see the code - the complete code - first...